# Did Evelyn Waugh ever attempt to write a screenplay?

Tags: evelyn-waugh

Waugh's early novels, especially *Vile Bodies*, are notable for a "cinematic" style of pacing, with relatively short segments of narrative being "cross-cut" to build tension.

It's noted in [his Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Waugh) that he spent time in Hollywood trying to get a film production of *Brideshead Revisted* made, but it's unclear from the article whether he was there merely in the capacity of the owner of the rights, or actually working as a writer for the studio.

Did Waugh write any screenplays, either working for a studio or on his own?

Answer (score 3):

According to *[Evelyn Waugh: a Biography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1856192237)*, a biography of him written by Selina Hastings, he did write plays if not screenplays.

According to her, Waugh performed plays as a child:

> he and the other schoolyard children performed plays, usually written by Waugh.

<sup>(pp 30-32)</sup>

Now these aren't screenplays, but it does show he had some experience with plays in general. (though yes, films often do have more cuts and scene shifts than physical plays)

Comment: thanks for this.  I really am looking for screenplays.  Does the Hastings biography include anything more?

Comment: @KevinTroy not in this area, not as far as I remember. I'll keep looking though and update the answer when/if I find something. Sorry.